# Populating mongodb in one unit test intereferes with another unit test

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to run all of my unit tests asynchronously, but calling a function to populate the database with some dummy data interferes with the other unit tests that run at the same time and that make use of the same data.

collectionSeed.js file:

```
const {ObjectID} = require('mongodb');

import { CollectionModel } from "../../models/collection";

const collectionOneId = new ObjectID();
const collectionTwoId = new ObjectID();

const collections = [{
  _id: collectionOneId
}, {
  _id: collectionTwoId
}];

const populateCollections = (done) => {
    CollectionModel.remove({}).then(() => {
      var collectionOne = new CollectionModel(collections[0]);
      collectionOne.save(() =>{
        var collectionTwo = new CollectionModel(collections[1]);
        collectionTwo.save(() => {
            done();
        });
      });
    });
};
```

unitTest1 file:

```
beforeEach(populateCollections);

it('Should run', (done) => {
 //do something with collection[0]
})
```

unitTest2 file:

```
beforeEach(populateCollections);

it('Should run', (done) => {
 //do something with collection[0]
})
```

I'm running unit tests that change, delete, and add data to the database, so using `beforeEach` is preferable to keep all of the data consistent, but the `CollectionModel.remove({})` functions often run in between an `it` function from one file and a second `it` function inside the other unit test file, so one unit test is working fine, while the second `it` is trying to use data that doesn't exist.

Is there anyway to prevent the different unit test files from interfering with each other?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you create a database per test file, for example adding to the DB name the name of the file. So you just have to take care of tests not interfering inside the same file, but you can forget about tests in other files.

I think that managing fixtures is one the most troublesome parts of unit testing, so with this, creating and fixing unit tests is going to become smoother.

As a trade off, each test file will take more execution time; but in my opinion in most of the cases it is worth enough.

Ideally each test should be independent of the rest, but, in general, that would take way too much overhead, so I recommended the `once per test file` approach.